# SAS Chars obs in Numeric column

Tags: sas, char, format, numeric

I have a numeric column and it has Chars values. I need to extract the string but if I convert to char the column it extracts a number. How can I extract the string?

Comment: Can you give some examples? What is in the numeric column that has chars values. What the raw data looks like and what string you'd like to have? Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to provide more details. Please review the guidelines on how to ask a question here [ask]. Specifically, we need to know what you mean by numeric column? is that in a a CSV or data set you're trying to read? SAS data sets wouldn't allow that to occur. So you'll need to read it as a character and change it after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

Are you meaning to get strings that can not be convert into numbers? Try this:

```
if input(rawvar,??best.) = . then newvar = rawvar;
```